# Alguna forma de crear enemigos en posicion random mas real? JS - PHASER3

Tags: javascript, phaser3

Estoy creando un pequeno juego en JS, pero para crear los enemigos en una posicion random lo estoy haciendo de esta forma:

```
 resetShip(enemy_spaceship) {
        enemy_spaceship.y = 0;
        enemy_spaceship.x = Phaser.Math.Between(2,globalThis.config.width);   
        
 }
```

es un metodo que sacara un numero random del 2 hasta la longitud de la pantalla, es decir 500, el problema es que a veces los sprites salen muy pegados uno a los otros, asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pense en utilizar el delta, es decir que despues de cada x tiempo sacar un enemigo, pero igualmente a veces salen pegados o juntos, ya que el random pudo haber sacado 2,589 y el otro 2,587, por eso es que salen asi, alguna manera de evitarlo o de crear enemigos de forma aleatoria sin andar pegandose? gracias :)

Comment: Lo que podrías hacer es  que cuando salgan valores cercados de random, le añadas un distanciamiento, por ejemplo puedes restar los dos valores           
 (2,589 -2,587) en valor absoluto y si la resta de esos valores es  un numero pequeño (tu le pones el limite), entonces le sumas un valor a ese random, para que tome  una distancia adecuada un sprite del otro, obviamente controlando que no exceda el limite de la pantalla

Answer (score 0):

Tenes que ir guardandote en un array la posición todos los enemigos que hay actualmente en pantalla, y al momento de generar un nuevo enemigo, chequear que la posición que es dada aleatoriamente no esté ocupada por ningun otro enemigo. Tené en cuenta el tamaño en pixeles de tus enemigos:

```
var enemiesWidth = 20
var aliveEnemies = [200,400,900]

 function resetShip(enemy_spaceship) {
        enemy_spaceship.y = 0;
        enemy_spaceship.x = null
        while (!(enemy_spaceship.x)){
           let isValid = true
           let new_x = Phaser.Math.Between(2,globalThis.config.width);
           aliveEnemies.forEach((enemie) => {
               if (new_x >= (enemie - enemiesWidth)) {//miro hacia la izquierda
                    if (new_x <= (enemie + enemiesWidth)){ //miro hacia la derecha
                      isValid = false //si tiene alguno marco esta posicion como invalida
                    }
                   }
                 })
           if (isValid) enemy_spaceship.x = new_x ; // si es valido guardo la posicion para que salga del loop
        }
 }
```

Por ejemplo en el caso anterior, tomo un ejemplo de enemigos que miden 20px y al colocarlos chequeo tanto que no tenga ningun enemigo colocado ni a la izquierda ni a la derecha.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda, saludos!